# Ansible: Delete interfaces that are not in my host_vars

Tags: ansible

I've an ansible playbook that creates `l3_subinterfaces` on a Palo Alto firewall, the creating is based on the `host_vars` of the firewall.

```yaml
- l3_subinterfaces:
  - tag: "9"
    vr_name: "vr_production"
    ip: "10.0.9.2/24"
    comment: "VLAN9 Subinterface"
    parent_if: "ethernet1/1"
    zone: "Infrastructuur"
  - tag: "13"
    vr_name: "vr_production"
    ip: "10.0.13.2/24"
    comment: "VLAN13 Subinterface"
    parent_if: "ethernet1/2"
    zone: "Infrastructuur"
```

And the playbook task which create the interfaces:

```yaml
- name: Configure l3_subinterfaces
  panos_l3_subinterface:
    provider: "{{ panos_provider }}"
    name: "{{ item.parent_if }}.{{ item.tag }}"
    tag: "{{ item.tag }}"
    ip: ["{{ item.ip }}"]
    vr_name: "{{ item.vr_name }}"
    zone_name: "{{ item.zone }}"
    comment: "{{ item.comment }}"
    enable_dhcp: false
  with_items: 
    - "{{ l3_subinterfaces }}"
  when: l3_subinterfaces is defined
```

So at this point everything is working fine. However the thing I'm trying to achieve is holding the state of the firewall in the Ansible inventory.

So for example I'm now delete the `l3_subinterface` with tag `13` and run the task again, it still have the `l3_subinterface` with tag `13` configured on the Palo Alto firewall.

I'm trying to figure out how I can delete the `l3_subinterfaces` which exists on the firewall, but doesn't exists in my `host_vars`. I think I need to compare something like te facts with the host_vars, but really have no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've already found my own answer. The solution is to compare the list l3_subinterfaces against the palo alto interfaces:

```
- name: Get interfaces facts
  panos_facts:
    provider: '{{ panos_provider }}'
    gather_subset: ['interfaces']

- name: Delete unused l3_subinterfaces
  panos_l3_subinterface:
    provider: "{{ panos_provider }}"
    name: "{{ item }}"
    tag: "{{ item|regex_search('\\d+$') }}"
    state: "absent"
  with_items:
    - "{{ ansible_net_interfaces|selectattr('tag', 'defined')|map(attribute='name')|list | difference(l3_subinterfaces|map(attribute='name')|list) }}"
```